# Codeigniter Datamapper - self-relationship - include_related()

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-datamapper

I am looking at how to create self-relationship (upsteam) join in ORM Datamaper. 
my self - relation class looks:

```
<?php
class Prospect extends DataMapper{

    var $has_one =array(
        'parent' => array(
            'class' => 'prospect',
            'other_field'=>'prospect'
        ),
        'prospect' => array(
        'other_field' => 'parent'
        )
    );




}
```

and I try to list

```
include_related (parent)
$p->include_related('parent')->get();
```

I have had error
Fatal error:  Cannot use object of type Prospect as array in `[..]application/libraries/Datamapper.php` on line 2739

I can do

```
$p->include_related('prospect')->get();
```

but in this case I have had a wrong join.

```
SELECT `prospects`.*, `prospect_prospects`.`id` AS prospect_id, `prospect_prospects`.`name` LEFT OUTER JOIN `prospects` prospect_prospects ON `prospects`.`id` = `prospect_prospects`.`parent_id`
```

Results shows relation parent -> child (downstream relation) not child-> parent (upstream relation)
I am lookig for:

```
SELECT `prospects`.*, `prospect_prospects`.`id` AS prospect_id, `prospect_prospects`.`name` LEFT OUTER JOIN `prospects` prospect_prospects ON `prospects`.`parent_id` = `prospect_prospects`.`id`
```

Any tips how to do it, and what I have to change it ? and how should look a good upstream relationship class / php code ?

ps: direct SQL query works brilliant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, Problem solved 
variable **parent** is used in Datamapper library class to keep an array with relations, so 'parent' is restricted and it **couldn't** be used at all. i.e. in my case. I have changed from **parent** to **parent_company** and all is working brilliant. (this is solved my left join problem as well).

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're dealing with is a "Reciprocal" relationship. Take a look at this page: http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/pages/advancedrelations.html

Go down to the section titled **"Many-to-Many Reciprocal Self Relationships"** and see if that helps you.

In essence, it should be a matter of adding reciprocal to the properties:

```
<?php
class Prospect extends DataMapper{

    var $has_one =array(
        'parent' => array(
            'class' => 'prospect',
            'other_field'=>'prospect',
            'reciprocal' => TRUE
        ),
        'prospect' => array(
            'other_field' => 'parent', 
            'reciprocal' => TRUE
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: parent is prohibited, based on my source code of datamapper -> parent is used and It shouldn't be use to create relation

Comment: Reciprocal Self Relationships are needed when you want to maintain the relation both ways, and you have a setup with two FK's (a many-2-many or has_many's both ways).

If enabled and you create a relation, the relation in the other direction is added automatically.

Comment: WanWizard -> yes, I know. It would be good if you publish list of the restricted namespaces (as parent). BTW: you library is great :) THX for it